# wso2 micro-gateway x-wso2-disable-security=true disable throttling

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-gateway

I am trying to have basic authentication on below defined api. i have disabled default security using ***x-wso2-disable-security: true*** but it also disables rate limiting defined on it.
No sure why this is the case.

````
paths:
  /public/rt/PING:
    get:
      description: ""
      operationId: PING
      x-wso2-throttling-tier: 6PerMin
      x-wso2-disable-security: true
      x-wso2-request-interceptor: setAuthHeaderInRequest
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/PING"
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/PING"
      security:
        - basicAuthentication: []```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed[2] in the newest version(3.1.0) of microgateway[1]

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-microgateway/releases/tag/v3.1.0

[2] - https://github.com/wso2/product-microgateway/issues/1099

Comment: is this officially released? As documentation still says "This version is a work in progress." Also wasn't able to generate docker image for 3.1.0 .. fails with error  : Generating docker artifacts... error [docker plugin]: module [wso2/petstore:3.1.0] unable to connect to server: Host name may not be null

Comment: Yes, this officially released now. How did you create the docker image

Comment: after setting dockerHost = 'localhost' in deployment-config.toml it worked.